# Steps to obtain integer solution to 2 equations sharing 3 variables?

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, natural-numbers

I want to calculate possible T natural numbers for which the following two equations are true:

$$T=8x+7 $$
$$T=6y+5$$

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%3D8x%2B7%2CT%3D6y%2B5) gives me the function:

> Integer solution:
> $T = 24 n + 23$, where $x = 3 n + 2$ and $y = 4 n + 3$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$

I have not done real math since High School, decades ago. What steps does one follow to get to that function?

P.S.: [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/t%3D8x%2B7%2C%20t%3D6y%2B5) returns something that I cannot see how it maps to WA’s answer. How are both results related?

Comment: Well, do you know modular congruences? If yes, then I have an answer :)

Comment: I don’t, but even if I may not understand your answer right away, I can use it to search so by all means, any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equating the two expressions for $T$, and simplifying:
$$8x+7=6y+5\\
8x+2=6y\\
4x+1=3y$$
The RHS is a multiple of $3$, so the left hand side needs to be a multiple of $3$ as well. If you just try some values $0,1,2,3..$ for $x$, you will find that the only ones that make $4x+1$ a multple of $3$ are $2,5,8,11,...$. It is easy to see that this pattern continues, as adding a multiple of $3$ to $x$ will not affect whether the left hand side is divisible by $3$. So we get that $x=3n+2$ for some integer $n$.

A more formal way to solve this is by [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), where all multiples of $3$ are ignored:
$$4x+1\equiv3y \pmod 3\\
3x+x+1\equiv3y \pmod 3\\
x+1\equiv0 \pmod 3\\
x\equiv-1 \pmod 3\\
x\equiv-1+3=2 \pmod 3\\
x=3n+2$$

Subtituting this into $4x+1=3y$ we get
$$4(3n+2)+1=3y\\
12n+8+1=3y\\
12n+9=3y\\
4n+3=y$$

So we get that $y=4n+3$ and $x=3n+2$. Substituting either of these into one of the expressions for $T$ gives that $T=24n+23$.

Symbolab gives a different answer because it does not know that you want $x,y$ to be integers. It expresses $T$ and $y$ in terms of $x$, but the expression for $y$ is as a fraction. To make that fraction simplify and get an integer $y$, you would still need to restrict the values of $x$ to $x=3n+2$ for integer $n$.